# Changing Icon not causing repaint on JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jtabbedpane

I have a strange issue. I have a JTabbedPane which has several JPanels added as children.

One of these panels has an ImageIcon along with a label. The actual Image used by this ImageIcon is being changed periodically based on what is happening in the associated JPanel.

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

Certain events in the second tab cause the red icon to change.

When these events happen I change the Image using the following method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#setImage(java.awt.Image)

However after I have set the image, the actual tab is not repainting. It is only repainting on other events (such as mouse over or click).

I would have thought that changing an icons image would cause it to trigger a repaint on anything that is using that icon? Is there some trick to getting this to work?

I could probably implement a hacky solution by creating a custom icon class and passing a JComponent to it which will be repainted when the image is changed, however this would bring up another problem of repainting the entire JTabbedPane every time the icon changes OR calculating the area the icon is occupying and repainting that (which seems like a lot of effort).

EDIT:

Here is a simple application which demonstrates my problem. Assuming two images located in the src root directory named Image1.png and Image2.png.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JTabbedPaneTest {

    JFrame jFrame;

    JTabbedPane jTabbedPane;
    ImageIcon testIcon;

    BufferedImage image1;
    BufferedImage image2;

    Timer timer;

    public JTabbedPaneTest() throws IOException {

        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        image1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Image1.png"));
        image2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Image2.png"));

        testIcon = new ImageIcon(image1);

        jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", testIcon, new JPanel());
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", new JPanel());

        jFrame.add(jTabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Changing image...");
                if(testIcon.getImage() == image1){
                    testIcon.setImage(image2);
                }
                else {
                    testIcon.setImage(image1);
                }
            }
        });

        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JTabbedPaneTest application = new JTabbedPaneTest();
                    application.jFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The tab itself is not repainted automatically and requires another event to trigger the painting.

Comment: Works fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Are you using `SwingUtilities.invoke*` methods for setting the image?

Comment: It works fine here, maybe something is wrong with the L&F you are using. Try it with the system L&F rather than a custom one for test.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the response!

I tried turning off the Substance L&F that I am using but the problem still exists. I'll post a code example in the next few minutes if the SwingUtilities.invoke doesn't work.

Comment: Just tried using SwingUtilities.invokeLater and removing the L&F but the problem is still occurring. I'll try to whip up a really simple demonstration now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not painted then call `repaint()` after changing the icon.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Changing image...");
            if (testIcon.getImage() == image1) {
                testIcon.setImage(image2);
            } else {
                testIcon.setImage(image1);
            }
            jTabbedPane.repaint();//calling repaint after icon change
        }
```

Comment: I have a version like this which works but that means I need to keep a reference to wherever the icon is being used, which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JTabbedPane#setIconAt` to set the new icon. A modified source is below that works.

```
package ant.test;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JTabbedPaneTest {

    JFrame jFrame;

    JTabbedPane jTabbedPane;
    ImageIcon testIcon1;
    ImageIcon testIcon2;

    BufferedImage image1;
    BufferedImage image2;

    Timer timer;

    public JTabbedPaneTest() throws IOException {

        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        image1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Image1.png"));
        image2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Image2.png"));

        testIcon1 = new ImageIcon(image1);
        testIcon2 = new ImageIcon(image2);

        jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", testIcon1, new JPanel());
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", new JPanel());

        jFrame.add(jTabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Changing image...");
                if(jTabbedPane.getIconAt(0) == testIcon1){
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            jTabbedPane.setIconAt(0, testIcon2);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            jTabbedPane.setIconAt(0, testIcon1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JTabbedPaneTest application = new JTabbedPaneTest();
                    application.jFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Incidentally, using `SwingUtilities#invoke*` methods is good practice.